# adding variable number of rows to a datatable

Tags: vb.net, datatable

I have a form containing 360 lines of data. I need to add these data to a datatable. But if there is a duplicate, it should only update the row containing that data. And the number of duplicates can range from 0 to 180. Is it possible to do so in vb.net 3.5? If so, how?

Comment: What is a "line of data", have  you tried anything?

Comment: @Tim Schmelter: a line of data is 3 columns of data with one of them being of primary importance to me, in the sense that i don't need its duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [DataTable.LoadDataRow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b5abehtz.aspx) method.
This requires that you define the primary key of the table.
The primary key is used by the method to identify the duplicate row

```
Dim dt = new DataTable("test")
Dim col = dt.Columns.Add("ID", Type.GetType("System.Int32"))
col.AllowDbNull = false
col.Unique = true
dt.Columns.Add("Name", Type.GetType("System.String"))
..... ' and so on '

' now the primary key
Dim columns(1) As DataColumn
columns(0) = dt.Columns("ID")
dt.PrimaryKey = columns

' And then the LoadDataRow
Dim newRow As Object() = New Object(1) {}
newRow(0) = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text)
newRow(1) = TextBox2.Text
dt.LoadDataRow(newRow, True)
....
```

If one or more of your textbox1.Text contains the same id, the previous rows will be updated with the new values otherwise a new row will be added to the datatable

**EDIT**
Seeing your comment about a sum operation on the Quantity column then you should change the approach
(Of course add a third column with the numeric type desidered)

```
' Search if the ID is already present '
Dim rows = dt.Select("ID=" & TextBox1.Text)
if rows.Length == 0 Then
   ' No ID found, add a newrow to the datatable'
   Dim newRow = dt.NewRow()
   newRow(0) = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text)
   newRow(1) = TextBox2.Text
   newRow(2) = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox3.Text)
   dt.Rows.Add(newRow)
Else
   ' ID found, the Rows array should be of just one row and the second column incremented of the quantity '
   rows(0)(2) +=  Convert.ToInt32(TextBox3.Text)
End If
```

**EDIT**

```
Dim dt As New DataTable 
'adding columns to the datatble'
dt.Columns.Add("Operation") 
dt.Columns.Add("folder") 
' This is a numeric column, so tell it to the framework
dt.Columns.Add("quantity", Type.GetType("System.Int32"))

'adding datarows 
' The search is on a string column, so enclose in single quotes 
' I assume that a 'folder' names doesn't contains a single quote
Dim rows = dt.Select("folder='" & L1F1.Text + "'") 
If rows.Length = 0 Then 
   Dim newRow = dt.NewRow() 
   newRow(0) = L1Ob1.Text 
   newRow(1) = L1F1.Text 
   newRow(2) = Convert.ToInt32(L1Qty1.Text) 
   dt.Rows.Add(newRow) 
Else 
   rows(0)(2) += Convert.ToInt32(L1Qty1.Text) 
End If
```

Comment: and what should i do if i wanted to sum up the values?

Comment: Which values? This is just a pseudocode based on your question. I can't be more precise without knowing your data structure

Comment: sure... i have 3 columns... Id, Name, and Quantity, which is an integer... So, if the name has been repeated more than once, the quantities need to be summed up... Is it possible to do so?

Comment: No, LoadDataRow will search for your primary key (ID?) and if it finds a match then it will substitute the other two values with the values of the added row. If you need a sum by ID then you need a different approach: Search, then sum. I will try to update the answer

Comment: yes... Id would be the primary key... but i cannot afford to keep substituting the Qty value... i need their sum... please try and cook sth up...

Comment: :i am getting an error, missing operand after '1' operator... also, my id is not an integer, but is a text... so what should i do now? and do i have to write this code for all the textboxes or writing for just one is enough?

Comment: `Dim dt As New DataTable
  'adding columns to the datatble
        dt.Columns.Add("Operation")
        dt.Columns.Add("folder")
        dt.Columns.Add("quantity")

        'adding datarows
                Dim rows = dt.Select("folder=" & L1F1.Text)
        If rows.Length = 0 Then
            Dim newRow = dt.NewRow()
            newRow(0) = L1Ob1.Text
            newRow(1) = L1F1.Text
            newRow(2) = Convert.ToInt32(L1Qty1.Text)
            dt.Rows.Add(newRow)
        Else
                        rows(0)(2) += Convert.ToInt32(L1Qty1.Text)
        End If`

Comment: Thanks... the column folder does not include a single quote, but it does contain a "/"... also, the code adds only one row to the datatable... and i need as many rows as there are unique datas... how to achieve that?

Comment: Include the code above in a sub/function and pass the three values to be inserted in the database. (You should build the table before and then pass also the table to the function that adds the values)